# How can I make my file suitable for BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I read "example.txt" file into list called "lines".

Now I want to parse it with `BeautifulSoup: parsed = BeautifulSoup(lines.content, "lxml")`, but it throws an error: **'list' object has no attribute 'content'**.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should feed it a string with file content.

```
parsed = BeautifulSoup(open('example.txt').read(), "lxml")
```

Answer (score 0):

You read file into a list, and list has no attribute content. Beautiful soup expects string, so collapse lines into string by using str.join.

```
parsed = BeautifulSoup("".join(lines),"lxml")
```